# How to check if Session::has('loggedOn') and call a controller in a view?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel and can't manage to to check whether the user is logged on or not, before accessing page trough URL directly.

```
I suppose the check should be done in the routes and there is no problem to do so when calling a view from the route:

Route::get('/', function()
    {
    if (!Session::has('loggedOn'))
        {
        return view('viewLogin');
        }
    else
        {
        return view('viewAllData');
        }
    });
    enter code here

But when I want to call a Controller and check if (!Session::has('loggedOn')), how is this done?

Route::get('/messagesPage', 'MsgsController@messages');
```

Comment: Laravel has Auth::check method to check if used it logged in or not unless you have implemented custom login and session handling..

Comment: Thank you, I will then look for Auth::check in the documentation. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the below will see if the user is logged in

add

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

to your controller and the below to check

```
if (Auth::check()) {
// The user is logged in...
}
```

edited to add answer for second question

```
Route::get('profile', function () {
// Only authenticated users may enter...
})->middleware('auth');
```

the above will only let a user access the path if they are logged in

Comment: Thanks! Can I check whether the user is logged on  before redirecting to Controller(in routes)?

Comment: yes, you can, see edited answer above, if this answered your question please mark as accepted.

Comment: Please just tell me how to call a Controller using  Route::get('profile', function () {
// Only authenticated users may enter...
})->middleware('auth');

Comment: To verify user has first logged on I transformed this Route::any('/authorInput', 'BooksAuthorsController@authorInput'); to Route::get('/authorInput', function () {
App::make("BooksAuthorsController")->authorInput();
})->middleware('auth');  but it doesnt work